# Why does "key in mydict is True" return false when the key truly is in the list?

Tags: python, pandas

I have tested a simple loop which doesn't work...
If the "selected_cate" input is in the dictionnary values CATE.values(), it is supposed to print a messsage saying that it worked and add it in the global dataframe (column categ) data.categ[index].
When I give an input which is clearly in the dictionnary, it still doesn't work while the line tried alone work for the true statement !! (see the picture).

(in the test line "LIBELLE" replaces "lib" in the code, it is only a simple string)

```
for i in data.index:
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None  # default='warn'
lib=data.libelle[i]
if data.categ[i]=='AUTRE':

    while True:
        selected_cate=input("___# " + lib + " #___ "+" va dans quelle catégorie ? ").upper()
        if selected_cate in CATES.values() is True: 
            print("Dictionnary CATES contains selected_case")
            data.categ[i]= selected_cate
            break
        else:
            print("erreur : catégorie non reconnue")
```

Thanks for helping[image]

Comment: Not clear what you want to achieve and what is your problem.

Comment: Try to make your question title clear enough that someone can tell if they have the same problem just by reading it. Any number of completely unrelated problems could cause the wrong side of an `if` to be taken, so this title isn't really useful.

Comment: Also, **don't** post screenshots of code -- instead, transcripts of code or REPL sessions should be included as text. See [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122) on [meta].

Comment: Ok, sorry for being unclear, i'll make an effort next time. I have my answer

Answer (score 1):

It probably comes from the parentheses :

```
1 == 1 is True 
# returns False beause equivalent with 1 == (1 is True)

(1 == 1) is True 
# returns True
```

Therefore you should use

```
if (selected_cate in CATES.values()) is True:
```

that actually boils down to

```
if selected_cate in CATES.values():
```

Comment: got it thanks a lot

Comment: `if selected_cate in CATES.values() is True` is not equivalent to `if selected_cate in (CATES.values() is True)`

Comment: Indeed, I do not know how `if selected_cate in CATES.values() is True` is parsed.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

```
 selected_cate in CATES.values() is True
```

is not the same as

```
selected_cate in CATES.values()
```

In the first case the `is`  operator is chained to the `in` operator so the line is equivalent to

```
selected_cate in CATES.values() and CATES.values() is True
```

which is false.

There are many subtleties with the `is` operator that might depend on your Python implementation/version. For instance small integers are often cached so two 1s might be the same object in memory but not two 500000s...

```
In [32]: 1+1 is 2
Out[32]: True
In [33]: 5000+1 is 5001
Out[33]: False
```

The general recommendation is to avoid using `is` unless you really want to know if it is the same object in memory.